# How to get string between the last two "/" symbols

Tags: bash, shell, string-manipulation

I am using Bash. I have some string of paths, like `/dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext` and I want to extract the string `dir2` in bash.
You can assume that the word I want to extract is located between the two last `/` characters.

I am trying to combine `##` and `%` but with poor results.

What I tried and does not work is `cut=${${path%/*}##*/}`.

How can I do that?

**Solved** but looking for **alternatives**.
My solution is the following:

`cut=$(tmp=${path%/*}; echo ${tmp##*/})`

Comment: `basename $(dirname /dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext)` or `echo /dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext | awk -F '/' '{print $(NF-1)}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
s="/dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext"
[[ $s =~ ([^/]*)/[^/]*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
dir2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with Bash (also two steps).

```
IFS=/ read -a array <<<'/dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext'
echo ${array[ $(( ${#array[@]}-2 )) ]}
dir2
```

Comment: what is the `<<<`?

Comment: @Nisba: It's a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the parsing in stages:-

```
path=/dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext
dir=${path%/*}
lastdir=${dir##*/}
```

By attempting to combine both parsing operations, you were attempting to use a string instead of a variable in the second expansion: this is not supported.

Note that you can use the same variable name for both `dir` and `lastdir`, eg:-

```
cut=${path%/*}; cut=${cut##*/}
```

You haven't said that your shell is `bash`, but I have assumed this from your code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using awk :

```
echo "/dir0/dir1/dir2/filename.ext" | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

The output of above will be:

```
dir2
```